# Is it possible to access a Spring Web App on Tomcat at /?

Tags: tomcat

I've managed to set up a web app that uses the Spring MVC framework, and I can access it at http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCTutorial/. Is it possible though to configure Tomcat so that I can access it at http://localhoust:8080/? If I were to ever use this for a real web app, I wouldn't want to have the extra /.../ after my domain. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Yes. / is the ROOT webapp. So name it `ROOT.war` and drop it in the webapps directory.